# Using ngFor with an index representing the row where I am

Tags: angular

I've just started to learn Angular 4 and I have trying to use this array:

```
public productsByLaw: IHash;
interface IHash {
    [row: number]: IProduct[];
}
```

The `productsByLaw` will store an `IProduct` array for each row I will display in a `<table>`.

In a `ngFor` (in the second one of this example):

```
<tr *ngFor="let productionorder of productionorders; let rowIndex = index">
<td>
    <select id="ProductId-{{rowIndex}}" name="ProductId-{{rowIndex}}" #productId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="productionorders[rowIndex].productid" required>
        <option></option>
        <option *ngFor="let product of productsByLaw[{{rowIbdex}}]" [value]="product.productId">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

But I get a syntax error here: `productsByLaw[{{rowIndex}}]` with the `{{rowIndex}}`.

I want to use the `IProduct[]` array depending on the row where I am.

How can I do what I what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
productsByLaw[rowIndex]
```

`{{}}` is only for string interpolation

Bindings with `*` (like in `*ngFor="..."` or `[foo]="..."` are evaluated as expressions and not strings.